# Equivalent of crypto.getRandomValues and Uint32Array in Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, cryptography

What is the equivalent Python expression for this Javascript expression?

```
console.log(window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(4)).join(''))
```

Basically need to get a cryptographically strong random value that is generated from Uint32Array (Which represents an array of 32-bit unsigned integers in the platform byte order).

This is what I have done so far -

```
import random
str1 = ""
for x in range(6):
  str1 += random.randint(0,9999999999)
print str1
```

It gives me a value but I don't think its cryptographically strong.

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I improved the question. Do remove the downvote if you find the new question satisfactory.

Comment: Have you considered using `os.urandom(number_of_bytes)`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom Another option might be to consider the `secrets.randbits(random_bits_needed)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.randbits

Comment: I agree with @SudheeshSinganamalla, your best bet is the secrets library if you are looking for a crypto logically random value.

Comment: `random.randint()` is not a cryptographic randomizer and should not be used for security purposes. Follow the advice in @SudheeshSinganamalla comment.

Comment: Thanks guys. With help from the comments here I was able to solve it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the answer thanks to comments above.

Here is the Javascript version:

```
console.log(window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(4)).join(''))
```

Here is the Python equivalent(Only works for Python3.6+):

For earlier versions use `pip install python2-secrets`

```
import secrets
randValue = "".join(map(str, [secrets.randbits(32) for i in range(4)]))
print(randValue)
```